# Magento 1.9 preselect of configurable options (swatches)

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches

Is there a way to have **Magento 1.9** auto select one of its simple products from a **configurable product** when page loaded?

Pre select first item is good enough for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using `rwd` theme, it can also be achieved by adding below jQuery code to your **catalog/product/view.phtml** file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".configurable-swatch-list li:first-child a").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).children("span").trigger("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can avhieve this thing.

**First way**

1) use ready extension , Marius Has created  one extension you can use his extension ,and you can easily set predefault simple product

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

**Second way**

2) You can  do all coding by your own for preselect option

Follow steps

Your `config.xml` code

```
<events>
      <catalog_controller_product_init_after>
          <observers>
            <catalog_product_view_init_attribute_selection_by_url>
              <type>model</type>
              <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
              <method>initSelection</method>
            </catalog_product_view_init_attribute_selection_by_url>
          </observers>
      </catalog_controller_product_init_after>
  </events>
```

and your observer code

```
public function initSelection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    if (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE == $product->getTypeId()) {
          $attribute_id = 92; //your attribute_id
          $optionValue  = 102;// attribute option id   
          $productData[$attribute_id] = $optionValue;
          $product->setData('preconfigured_values', new Varien_Object(array('super_attribute'=>$productData))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: better solution .....

Answer (score 2):

try prototype **simulate**

```
$('foo').simulate('click');
```

It will trigger click

or use jQuery

```
$('#foo').trigger( "click" );
```

here is complete code for blue color

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('attribute92').setValue(27);
var text=jQuery("#attribute92 option:selected").text();
jQuery('#select_label_color').html(text);
jQuery('#option27').addClass("selected");
jQuery('#attribute92').trigger('change');
jQuery(#option27').find("span").trigger('click');
</script>
```

Comment: we can do this thing with the observer and show preselect values

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala (customer must click on the options.) see that in question.

Comment: I have achieve that thing also , just need to check my old project code If I can find

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala this is most easy solution that why put here. hope you will find soon and share here

Comment: Mine is trickey.

Comment: I just edited my question, sorry to make it confused. But what I want is to have one of the options auto selected when page is loaded. Because as Magento standard, no options is selected until customer click on them. I want to have one option preselected by default when page loaded.

Comment: @Zhenyu you need id of option just pass it in place of ('foo') which you want to selected. that it

Comment: @QaisarSatti I share My code

Comment: @Zhenyu updated the code test and feedback.

Comment: good and easy one